# Finding probability of Y using a function for X

Tags: probability

The continuous random variable X has probability density function given by 
$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}1+x&-1\leq x\leq 0\\
1-x&0<x\leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The random variable $Y$ is defined by $Y=X^2$. Show that 
$$P(Y\leq y)=2\sqrt y-y, ~~~0\leq y\leq 1$$

$P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)=P(X\leq \pm \sqrt y)=F(\sqrt y)-F(-\sqrt y)$

Can somebody please tell me which intervals of $f(x)$ I have to use when determining $F(\sqrt y)$ and $F(-\sqrt y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by calculating first the function $\displaystyle{F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt}$. We have the following cases:

- For $x<-1$, $\displaystyle{F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt=0}$.
- For $-1\leq x\leq 0$, $$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,dt=\int_{-1}^x (1+t)\,dt=\left[t+\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right]_{-1}^x=x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\left(-1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}.$$
- For $0<x\leq 1$, \begin{align*}
  F(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} 0\,dt+\int_{-1}^0 (1+t)\,dt+\int_{0}^x (1-t)\,dt\\
  &=0+\dfrac{1}{2}+\left[t-\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right]_0^x=\dfrac{1}{2}+x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}.
  \end{align*}
- For $1<x$, $\displaystyle{F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,dt=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,dt=1}$.

Hence, the function $F(x)$ can be written as $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0 &x<-1\\ \dfrac{1}{2}+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2} &-1\leq x\leq 0\\ \dfrac{1}{2}+x-\dfrac{x^2}{2} &0<x\leq 1\\ 1 &1<x\end{cases}$$

Finally, to know how to calculate $F(\sqrt{y})$ and $F(-\sqrt{y})$, you can simply use the composition of these functions as follows:

$Y=X^2$ implies $0\leq Y$.

So, $P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)=P(|X|\leq \sqrt{y})=P(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq \sqrt{y})$

Thus, for $0\leq y\leq 1$, $0\leq \sqrt{y}\leq 1$ and

\begin{align*}
P(Y\leq y)&=P(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq \sqrt{y})=F(\sqrt{y})-F(-\sqrt{y})\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{y}-\frac{(\sqrt{y})^2}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+(-\sqrt{y})+\frac{(-\sqrt{y})^2}{2}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{2}+\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{2}\\
&=2\sqrt{y}-y
\end{align*}

and for $y>1$,

\begin{align*}
P(Y\leq y)&=P(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq \sqrt{y})=P(-1\leq X\leq \sqrt{y})\\
&=F(\sqrt{y})-F(-1)\\ 
&=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+(-1)+\dfrac{(-1)^2}{2}\right)\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you tell me why didn't you used the -1<x<0 interval of f(x)? Why only the 0<x<1 interval?

Comment: Sure. I did not use it because the function $\sqrt{y}$ only takes positive values, so there is no value of $y$ such that $-1\leq \sqrt{y}<0$.

Comment: But:$X^2=Y\implies X=±√Y$ now there are two intervals of x: $0<x<1$ and $-1<x<0$. $-1<x<0$ can be the valid interval for $-√y$.